# Node.js - ES6 module import to Node.js 'require'

Tags: node.js, es6-class

What is the Node.js 'require' equivalent to the following ES6 import?

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I got it working with:

```
var RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob').default;
```

For more details, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457345/npm-react-native-fetch-blob-rnfetchblob-fetch-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1#comment64320099_38457345).

Answer (score 1):

There's no default export in require so you don't have an exact equivalent.

The practice with node modules when you have only one value to export is to make it the module exports:

```
module.exports = ...
```

In such a case, you'll be able to import using

```
var RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob');
```

Comment: At least for Babel, you have to add a `.default` to access the default export.