# npm react-native-fetch-blob - "RNFetchBlob.fetch is not a function"

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, fetch

I am using the npm package [react-native-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob).
I have followed all the steps from the git repository to use the package.

I then imported the package using the following line:

```
var RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob');
```

I am trying to request a BLOB containing an image from the a server.

This is my main method.

```
fetchAttachment: function(attachment_uri) {

   var authToken = 'youWillNeverGetThis!'
   var deviceId = '123';
   var xAuthToken = deviceId+'#'+authToken

   //Authorization : 'Bearer access-token...',
   // send http request in a new thread (using native code)
   RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', config.apiRoot+'/app/'+attachment_uri, {

       'Origin': 'http://10.0.1.23:8081',
       'X-AuthToken': xAuthToken
    })
    // when response status code is 200
    .then((res) => {
       // the conversion is done in native code
       let base64Str = res.base64()
       // the following conversions are done in js, it's SYNC
       let text = res.text()
       let json = res.json()
    })
    // Status code is not 200
    .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
       // error handling
    });
}
```

I keep receiving the following error:

**"Possible Unhandled Promise Refection(id: 0): TypeError: RNFetchBlob.fetch is not a function".**

Any ideas?

Comment: Try var RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob').default;

Comment: @Cherniv it should be `import RNFetchBlob from ...` according to [the manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob#recipes). That's why `.default` is probably required.

Comment: @rmevans9 That worked. Write it up as an answer and I will accept the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are using ES5 style require statements with a library written against ES6/ES2015. You have two options:

ES5:

```
var RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob').default
```

ES6:

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'
```

Answer (score 1):

My import looks like this : import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

but I'v got an error : TypeError: RNFetchBlob.scanFile is not a function

My code:

```js
const downloadAudio = async () => {
    const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
    const meditationFilesPath =
      Platform.OS == 'android'
        ? `${fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/meditations/${id}`
        : `${fs.dirs.DocumentDir}/meditations/${id}`;
    let audio_URL = track;
    let options = {
      fileCache: true,
      path: meditationFilesPath + `/${id}.mp3`,
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        // Related to the Android only
        useDownloadManager: true,
        notification: true,
        path: meditationFilesPath + `/${id}.mp3`,
        description: 'Audio',
      },
    };
    try {
      const resAudio = await config(options).fetch('GET', audio_URL.uri);
      if (resAudio) {
        const audio = await RNFetchBlob.fs.scanFile([
          { path: resAudio.path(), mime: 'audio/mpeg' },
        ]);
        console.log('res -> ', audio);
        Alert.alert('Audio Downloaded Successfully.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error from downloadAudio', error);
    }
  };
```